# IE7-9 hover undetected on dropdown menu

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, hover

I'm building a dropdown menu. I've done this many times before, so I don't understand why it won't work this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All versions IE refuse to trigger the hover event upon my CSS dropdown menu. This works in chrome and FF but IE7, 8 and 9 will only show the dropdown menu when you hover over the link text, or a border set upon the `li` (see reference below).

So we're not wasting time, I will mention that I do have a `DOCTYPE` in my code. I also use Modernizr for other HTML5 elements. I have tried disabling this, no go. All links have a `href` attribute, none are empty, I've tried messing with floating the `li ul {}` instead of `position absolute`, etc.

Here is a perfect explanation of my problem. Unfortunately, their "fix" does not fix it for me: http://www.hopstudios.com/blog/internet_explorer_hover_li_bug_solution/

Here's my CSS. All of this is online at: http://allgodspeople.org/simplexdemo/

```
nav {
width: 530px;
float: right;
clear: right;
height: 78px;
overflow: visible;
}

nav * {
zoom: 1;}

nav ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
clear: none;
height: 53px;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 30px 0px;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
}
nav  a:link, nav  a:visited, nav  a:hover, nav  a:active {
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
color: #ffffff;
height: 23px; /*important for submenu positioning*/
text-decoration: none;
font-family: bebas;
padding: 0px 8px 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
height: 73px;
margin-top: -30px;}
nav li a:hover {
color: #e57914;
text-decoration: underline;
}
nav li.active a {
color: #e57914 !important;
}

/*Dropdown styles*/
nav li ul {
display: none;
float: left;
clear: both;
background: #444444;
border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 73px;
z-index: 999;
width: 200px;}
nav li:hover ul , nav li.hover ul{
display: block;}/*trigger the dropdown*/
nav li ul li {
background-color: #444444;
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
height: auto;
min-height: 23px;
padding: 0px 0px;
overflow: hidden;}
nav li ul a:link, 
nav li ul a:visited, 
nav li ul a:hover, 
nav li ul a:active {
display: block;
background-color: #444444;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 6px 15px;
margin: 0px;
width: 160px;
min-width: 160px;
margin: 0px;}
nav li ul a:hover {
background: #284f66;
color: #e57914;
text-decoration: none;}
nav li ul li:last-of-type a {
border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;}
```

PS. I've got my `@charset "UTF-8"` in there as well.

I've been researching this for hours, spent hours fooling with it in the IE inspector, and have found few documented examples of this, none of which solved my problem. I know that IE6 does not support li:hover correctly. I do not care about IE6 - but I never thought IE7, 8 and even IE9 would have this bug?

Anyone know how to fix this? Even a hack, if it looks good? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix? Rewrite the menu styles. I still don't know what went wrong, just that it disappeared when I rewrote my menu styles. My best guess is the fact that I switched the `<nav>` tag to a `<div id="navigation">` tag, and updated the CSS as such.

Thanks anyway everybody!